# dnsmasq multiplies A records

Tags: dns-servers, a-record

I'm using dnsmasq 2.80 on ubuntu 20.04.  In the configuration I set `hostsdir`, the files in this directory are read automatically.

If I change the IP of a host and checks the IP with the `dig` command, I get 2 A records, the new and the old one. If I change the IP again, I get 3  A records and so on ...

Example of the `dig` command:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> ddns.mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6174
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ddns.mydomain.com. IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ddns.mydomain.com. 0 IN A   10.8.0.105
ddns.mydomain.com. 0 IN A   10.8.0.104
ddns.mydomain.com. 0 IN A   10.8.0.102
```

How can i avoid the duplication of A records for the same host?

Every hint is welcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Strange that all 3 records have a TTL of zero.

Comment: @Kate TTL of zero is ok, that's the default behaviour of dnsmasq.